Enabling Java 8 feature crashes the React Native app
I am trying to enable the Java 8 feature in the React Native project because one of my Native modules uses Java 8 classes like LocalDateTime.
I have created a fresh React Native project. Since I am using Java 8 features in the Native Module, Java 8 coreLibraryDesugaring needs to be enabled in the parent App as well.
Currently, the app crashes when I declare coreLibraryDesugaring dependencies.
I am followed the Android documentation to enable it.
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#groovy
I am using React Native version: 0.75.2
Here is the stacktrace of the crash:.
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2086)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2392)
    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(ComponentInfo.java:130)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:212)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.system.ActivityManagerWrapper.getBadgedActivityLabel(ActivityManagerWrapper.java:709)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityTitle(RecentsTaskLoader.java:691)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.preloadPlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:280)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.preloadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:481)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel.preloadRecents(RecentsModel.java:157)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel$HandlerCallbacks.handleMessage(RecentsModel.java:289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2086)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2392)
    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(ComponentInfo.java:139)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:212)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.system.ActivityManagerWrapper.getBadgedActivityLabel(ActivityManagerWrapper.java:709)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityTitle(RecentsTaskLoader.java:691)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.preloadPlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:280)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.preloadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:481)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel.preloadRecents(RecentsModel.java:157)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel$HandlerCallbacks.handleMessage(RecentsModel.java:289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2086)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2392)
    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(ComponentInfo.java:130)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:212)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.system.ActivityManagerWrapper.getBadgedContentDescription(ActivityManagerWrapper.java:729)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateContentDescription(RecentsTaskLoader.java:714)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.preloadPlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:281)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.preloadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:481)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel.preloadRecents(RecentsModel.java:157)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel$HandlerCallbacks.handleMessage(RecentsModel.java:289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2086)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2392)
    at android.content.pm.ComponentInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(ComponentInfo.java:139)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:212)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.system.ActivityManagerWrapper.getBadgedContentDescription(ActivityManagerWrapper.java:729)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateContentDescription(RecentsTaskLoader.java:714)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.preloadPlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:281)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.preloadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:481)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel.preloadRecents(RecentsModel.java:157)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel$HandlerCallbacks.handleMessage(RecentsModel.java:289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2086)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getText(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2392)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadUnsafeLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:222)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadLabel(PackageItemInfo.java:212)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.system.ActivityManagerWrapper.getBadgedContentDescription(ActivityManagerWrapper.java:730)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateContentDescription(RecentsTaskLoader.java:714)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.preloadPlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:281)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.preloadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:481)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel.preloadRecents(RecentsModel.java:157)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel$HandlerCallbacks.handleMessage(RecentsModel.java:289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2086)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1792)
    at miui.theme.IconCustomizerUtils.getAdaptiveIconFromPackage(IconCustomizerUtils.java:55)
    at miui.content.res.IconCustomizer.getAdaptiveIcon(IconCustomizer.java:749)
    at miui.content.res.IconCustomizer.getIcon(IconCustomizer.java:666)
    at android.app.MiuiThemeHelper.getDrawable(MiuiThemeHelper.java:95)
    at android.content.res.IMiuiThemeHelperImpl.getDrawable(IMiuiThemeHelperImpl.java:40)
    at android.content.res.ThemeManagerStub.getDrawable(ThemeManagerStub.java:180)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3356)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3373)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3344)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:273)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.IconLoader.getBadgedActivityIcon(IconLoader.java:198)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.IconLoader.getAndInvalidateIfModified(IconLoader.java:169)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:728)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.preloadPlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:283)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.preloadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:481)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel.preloadRecents(RecentsModel.java:157)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel$HandlerCallbacks.handleMessage(RecentsModel.java:289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2086)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getResourcesForApplication(ApplicationPackageManager.java:2072)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getDrawable(ApplicationPackageManager.java:1792)
    at miui.content.res.IconCustomizer.getCustomizedNormalIcon(IconCustomizer.java:693)
    at miui.content.res.IconCustomizer.getIcon(IconCustomizer.java:669)
    at android.app.MiuiThemeHelper.getDrawable(MiuiThemeHelper.java:95)
    at android.content.res.IMiuiThemeHelperImpl.getDrawable(IMiuiThemeHelperImpl.java:40)
    at android.content.res.ThemeManagerStub.getDrawable(ThemeManagerStub.java:180)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3356)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadUnbadgedItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3373)
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.loadItemIcon(ApplicationPackageManager.java:3344)
    at android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadIcon(PackageItemInfo.java:273)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.IconLoader.getBadgedActivityIcon(IconLoader.java:198)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.IconLoader.getAndInvalidateIfModified(IconLoader.java:169)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.getAndUpdateActivityIcon(RecentsTaskLoader.java:728)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoadPlan.preloadPlan(RecentsTaskLoadPlan.java:283)
    at com.android.systemui.shared.recents.model.RecentsTaskLoader.preloadTasks(RecentsTaskLoader.java:481)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel.preloadRecents(RecentsModel.java:157)
    at com.miui.home.recents.RecentsModel$HandlerCallbacks.handleMessage(RecentsModel.java:289)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:224)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:318)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
Failed to open APK '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk': I/O error
failed to add asset path '/data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk'
java.io.IOException: Failed to load asset path /data/app/~~aWq9oQJ84Rr4Dfp2WRHYLg==/com.testprojecttwo-sLfQVKKcWR_8BtLu92RbLw==/base.apk
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.nativeLoad(Native Method)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.<init>(ApkAssets.java:298)
    at android.content.res.ApkAssets.loadFromPath(ApkAssets.java:147)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.loadApkAssets(ResourcesManager.java:487)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.-$$Nest$mloadApkAssets(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager$ApkAssetsSupplier.load(ResourcesManager.java:180)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createAssetManager(ResourcesManager.java:574)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResourcesImpl(ResourcesManager.java:661)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.findOrCreateResourcesImplForKeyLocked(ResourcesManager.java:715)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.createResources(ResourcesManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.ResourcesManager.getResources(ResourcesManager.java:1170)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:2748)


Here is the repository link of the project:
https://github.com/chinmaydash007/TestProjectTwo.git
Am I missing something while enabling Java 8 desugaring?
